# Different results when using bysort with more than one variable

Tags: sorting, stata

When I use the `bysort` prefix with just one variable and generate the mean of another variable, I get one set of values e.g. `42,43,39` etc.

```
bysort date: egen dailymean = mean(temperature) // Gives mean temp for each day
```

When I use `bysort` with two variables and generate a similar mean, I get a different value e.g. `49,48,51` etc.  I want to understand what the values signify.

```
bysort date isCentralPark: egen cpdailymean = mean(temperature)
```

In the first case, I think I am getting the mean of the temperature by the variable sorted by, date in other words daily mean temperature.

In the second, am I getting the daily mean temperature in Central Park or something different?

Answer (score 2):

The help file of `sort` clearly states:

> "***sort** arranges the observations of the current data into ascending order based on
>   the values of the variables in varlist...*"

The help file of `by` also clearly states:

> "*...**by** repeats the command for each group of observations for which the values of
>   the variables in varlist are the same...*"

So `bysort` simply sorts the data before a`by` operation.

You need to carefully study the extensive examples provided in the help files before you ask a question on here for something so fundamentally basic.

As the 
[Stata tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info) explains, 
"*...there is simply no replacement for acquainting yourself with the basic
concepts and syntax of Stata...*"

In the absence of example data, which despite repeated requests you failed to 
provide, here's a simple example of how the `varlist` affects `bysort`:

```
clear
set obs 15
set seed 1234567890

egen id = seq(), block(5)
generate a = rnormal()

bysort id: generate n1 = _n
list

     +---------------------+
     | id           a   n1 |
     |---------------------|
  1. |  1   -.6953015    1 |
  2. |  1   -.5804186    2 |
  3. |  1   -1.938336    3 |
  4. |  1    .9347979    4 |
  5. |  1    -.767854    5 |
     |---------------------|
  6. |  2    .3776966    1 |
  7. |  2   -.5545912    2 |
  8. |  2   -.0636268    3 |
  9. |  2    2.041136    4 |
 10. |  2   -.2200604    5 |
     |---------------------|
 11. |  3    .5418512    1 |
 12. |  3    1.174645    2 |
 13. |  3    .3234408    3 |
 14. |  3    -.544277    4 |
 15. |  3    .2121655    5 |
     +---------------------+
```

```
bysort id a: generate n2 = _n
list

     +--------------------------+
     | id           a   n1   n2 |
     |--------------------------|
  1. |  1   -1.938336    3    1 |
  2. |  1    -.767854    5    1 |
  3. |  1   -.6953015    1    1 |
  4. |  1   -.5804186    2    1 |
  5. |  1    .9347979    4    1 |
     |--------------------------|
  6. |  2   -.5545912    2    1 |
  7. |  2   -.2200604    5    1 |
  8. |  2   -.0636268    3    1 |
  9. |  2    .3776966    1    1 |
 10. |  2    2.041136    4    1 |
     |--------------------------|
 11. |  3    -.544277    4    1 |
 12. |  3    .2121655    5    1 |
 13. |  3    .3234408    3    1 |
 14. |  3    .5418512    1    1 |
 15. |  3    1.174645    2    1 |
     +--------------------------+
```

```
bysort id (a): generate n3 = _n
list

     +-------------------------------+
     | id           a   n1   n2   n3 |
     |-------------------------------|
  1. |  1   -1.938336    3    1    1 |
  2. |  1    -.767854    5    1    2 |
  3. |  1   -.6953015    1    1    3 |
  4. |  1   -.5804186    2    1    4 |
  5. |  1    .9347979    4    1    5 |
     |-------------------------------|
  6. |  2   -.5545912    2    1    1 |
  7. |  2   -.2200604    5    1    2 |
  8. |  2   -.0636268    3    1    3 |
  9. |  2    .3776966    1    1    4 |
 10. |  2    2.041136    4    1    5 |
     |-------------------------------|
 11. |  3    -.544277    4    1    1 |
 12. |  3    .2121655    5    1    2 |
 13. |  3    .3234408    3    1    3 |
 14. |  3    .5418512    1    1    4 |
 15. |  3    1.174645    2    1    5 |
     +-------------------------------+
```